# Rspec Controller Passing Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controllers

Below is the problem I am having.  I am not sure how to pass the correct params to this controller action.

### The code

```
def get_standards
   @standard_children, @temp = Standard.browse(params[:guid])
   @parent_standard = params[:guid]
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
end
```

### The Rspec

```
describe "Get Standards" do
 it "should return correct values" do
   @stateOne = mock_model(Standard, description: "beta")
   Standard.stub!(:browse).and_return(@stateOne, "temp")     
   assigns(:standard_children).should == @stateOne
   assigns(:parent_standard).should == 'one'
   get :get_standards, :params => {guid: 'one'}
 end
end
```

### The Error

```
 Failure/Error: assigns(:standard_children).should == @stateOne
 expected: #<Standard:0x3ffed4e53d88 @name="Standard_1001">
 got: nil (using ==)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```rails
describe "Get Standards" do
 it "should return correct values" do
   @stateOne = mock_model(Standard, description: "beta")
   Standard.stub!(:browse).and_return(@stateOne, "temp")     

   get :get_standards, :guid => 'one'
   assigns(:parent_standard).should == 'one' 
   assigns(:standard_children).should == @stateOne             
 end
end
```

Comment: try again and if it still doesn't work, then your code doesn't work. open `rails console` and try `standard_children, temp = Standard.browse('one')`, you should get `nil` for `standard_children`, this would explain a problem